# Assigning a template-generated class to a C struct with the same layout

Tags: c++, c, templates, data-structures, aggregation

If I understand correctly, the object ’A’ defined thus:

```
typedef struct {
    int n;
    float *p;
} myStruct;
myStruct A;
```

is an aggregate with exactly the same layout in memory as the object ‘B’ defined as:

```
template <typename T> class myTemplateClass
{
public:
    int n;
    T*  p;
};
myTemplateClass<float> B;
```

So, is there a more elegant way of assigning

```
A = B;
```

than having to write

```
A = *(reinterpret_cast< myStruct *>(&B));
```

every time?

My reason for asking is that I have to call a library function which exposes an interface with arguments of the form ‘myStruct’,  from code where holding my data in the form of myTemplateClass is a great deal more natural.

Comment: Can you modify either class? And if so, do you want to?

Comment: Do not use typedef struct in C++. However, if you have a C interface, give B a conversion operator

Comment: u pass the mystruct by reference through an api and it gets filled by reference, perhaps??Is that the way u intend to use it??

Comment: Maybe have a templated conversion function, with a specialization for `float` and `myStruct` that converts to the correct structure?

Comment: @Steve Jessop; I can modify the templated class more easily than the C struct, but I'd still rather not.

Comment: How many `myStruct` type structs do you have?  How big are such `struct`s, is copying the bits more than once a performance bottleneck?  How many `myTemplateClass<?>` templates do you have?  Which version of C++ are you compiling against, C++03, C++11 or C++14?  Which compiler and version?

Comment: Without modifying either type, you can at least use `std::memcpy(&A,&B,sizeof(A));`, that way you don't violate strict aliasing :-)

Comment: Don't tag a question about templates as a C question.  Templates are not a C issue.  You are messing the database.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This requires a bit of boilerplate.  Two functions per `myStruct`, and two functions per `template`.

In the namespace of `myStruct` inject these two functions:

```
auto members( myStruct& s ) {
  return std::tie(s.n, s.p);
}
auto members( myStruct const& s ) {
  return std::tie(s.n, s.p);
}
```

in C++11 you have to add a `decltype` clause to give the return value explicitly.  Basically `tie` the members in the exact order declared.

In the body of the `myTemplateClass`, declare a `friend` function `members` that does something similar:

```
template <typename T>
class myTemplateClass {
public:
  int n;
  T*  p;
  friend auto members( myTemplateClass<T>& self ) {
    return std::tie( self.n, self.p );
  }
  friend auto members( myTemplateClass<T> const& self ) {
    return std::tie( self.n, self.p );
  }
};
```

finally, write assign:

```
template<class Lhs, class Rhs>
void assign_by_members( Lhs& lhs, Rhs const& rhs ) {
  members(lhs) = members(rhs);
}
```

and we are done.

Anyone that declares a free function `members` that returns something assignable to the other `members` works.  `tie` does element-wise assign on references, so all is good.

Note that only the one being assigned **from** needs the `const&` overload of `members` and only the one being assigned **to** needs the `&` overload of `members`.  So if assignment always goes from `template` class to C-`struct`, you can halve that boilerplate.

If you don't like the `assign_by_members` syntax, you can override `operator O` as follows:

```
template <typename T>
class myTemplateClass {
public:
// ... see above for code that goes here
  template<class O,class=decltype(members(std::declval<O>())>
  operator O() const {
    O retval;
    assign_by_members( retval, *this );
    return retval;
  }
};
```

which also does a test to determine if the type converted to supports `members`.  You could go a step further and test if the `members` return value can be assigned to from the return value of `members(*this)`, but that adds more boilerplate.

Comment: thank you. I can see this is safer than my original approach, but I was hoping to reduce the overall boilerplate rather than add to it.

Comment: @Eos Pengwern You only have to write boilerplate once, and your original code violates the strict aliasing rules causing undefined behavior.

Comment: @EosPengwern Note that with the `operator O` solution, you end up writing `a = b` and it works.  Without it, you write `assign_by_members( a, b )`.  When we have compile-time reflection (this is being worked on by a working group as we speak), you'll be able to make `members` be mostly auto-written (write once, have it work on every type with only public members), and just implement `operator O` in each `template` and `assign_by_members` once somewhere.  But we aren't there yet.

Comment: @Yakk; I'm intrigued. I've never heard of 'overriding the O operator' before? Is 'O' arbitary here, or is there actually a default O operator in C++11? (If so I can't find anything about it in the usual sources). Can you tell me more?

Comment: @EosPeng At the end of my post above, I was talking about `template<class O> operator O()const` - a `template` conversion operator.  In the above answer, I also SFINAE guarded it so it only works on types for which `members(O)` is a valid call.

Comment: I understand. That's really neat!

Answer (score 1):

You could make `myTemplateClass<T>` derive from the correct `myStruct` depending on the type parameter. You can use template specialization for this:

```
template <typename T> class myTemplateClass;

// Specialization for float
template <> class myTemplateClass<float> : public myStruct {};

// Specialization for int
template <> class myTemplateClass<int> : public myOtherStruct {};

// And so on for other types...
```

This way, you can assign instances of `myTemplateClass<float>` to `myStruct`, and `myTemplateClass<int>` to `myOtherStruct`. (Bonus: You don't have to rely on the "same memory layout" guess.)

Comment: This is actually more or less what I'm doing at the moment; the problem is that there are actually many of these structs, and the templated classes have a lot of methods, so I end up with an extremely bloated lot of code which isn't difficult to write - it's mainly cut-and-pasted - but it's hard to maintain. I'm trying to maximise the usefulness of the templates by minimising the number of specialisations required.

Comment: @EosPengwern: at least you shouldn't have to copy and paste the methods, since you can use a type trait for the base class: `struct dummy {}; template <typename T> struct myParent { typedef dummy value;}; template <> struct myParent<float> { typedef myStruct value; }; template <typename T> class myTemplateClass : public typename myParent<T>::value { ... loads of methods ...};`

Comment: @Steve Jessop; that looks promising, but I haven't quite succeeded in wrapping my head around it. Is there any chance you could expand this comment into an answer? If it comprises what I think it does (but can't quite see) then I'll more than likely accept it.

Answer (score 0):

If you derive from mystruct, then, u can use a static_cast on it.
As suggested above, template specialization would work too.
I would take static_cast over reinterpret_cast any day.

Below is the working code.

```
typedef struct {
    int n;
    float *p;
} myStruct;
myStruct A;



template <typename T> class myTemplateClass:public myStruct
{
public:
    int n;
    T*  p;
};
//myTemplateClass<float> B;

typedef myTemplateClass<float> temp;


temp B;

int main()
{


    A = *(static_cast< myStruct *>(&B));
```

Comment: thank you, but see my note under reima's answer below. As a matter of fact, if 'temp' derives from 'myStruct' then 'A = B', without any cast at all, is just fine.

Comment: got your dilemma now.