# Having a template refer to a member from a jointly-inherited class

Tags: c++, templates, multiple-inheritance

It's obvious that the following code won't compile, because it gives an "undeclared identifier" error at the line 'n = n_init'. Nevertheless, to a human reader the intent is probably clear enough: I want to declare a template for a class which will never be instantiated by itself, but only by multiple inheritance alongside another class which is guaranteed to contain at minimum a member 'n' of type int and a member 'p' of type T*, but which (being a C struct obtained from elsewhere) I'm not at liberty to derive from another template containing these fields:

```
// In a C header file from elsewhere:
// ----------------------------------
typedef struct {
    float *p;
    int n;
} float_array_C;

// In my C++ header file:
// ----------------------

template<typename T> class MyArray
{
public:
    MyArray(int n_init)
    {
        n = n_init;   
        contents.resize(n);
        p = contents.data();
    }

    virtual void mustExist() = 0;

private:
    std::vector<T> contents; 
};


class float_array : public float_array_C, public MyArray<float>
{
public:
    float_array(int n) : float_array_C(), MyArray(n)
    {}

    virtual void mustExist() {}
};

...

float_array testArray(10);
```

I've also tried this approach, with equally little success:

```
typedef struct {
    float *p;
    int n;
} float_array_C;

template<typename T1, typename T2> class MyArray
{
public:
    MyArray(int n_init)
    {
        &T2::n = n_init;   
        contents.resize(n);
        &T2::p = contents.data();
    }

private:
    std::vector<T1> contents; 
};


typedef MyArray<float, float_array_C> floatArray;


...

float_array testArray(10);
```

Can this, or anything remotely similar to it, in fact be done?

Comment: The second approach might work if you actually derive from `T2`.  (`template <typename T1, typename T2> class MyArray : public T2`)  But instead you would want `T2::n = n_init;`.  (The address-of operator doesn't do anything for you here.)  [Here is a demo of this approach](http://ideone.com/IKA0JQ).

Comment: @cdhowie Wow! That does, in fact, work. Would you like to make that an answer so I can accept it

Comment: This looks very much like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28157895/assigning-a-template-generated-class-to-a-c-struct-with-the-same-layout that you asked a couple days ago and already has an accepted answer.

Comment: Why do you want to keep separate copies of the size and begin of a `vector<>`? You can always just obtain them from the `vector<>` itself. Moreover, the size of a `vector<>` may not fit into an `int`.

Comment: @Mark B You're right to spot the similarity, and it is indeed the same underlying problem, but this is a different aspect of it. The question a couple of days ago was to do with assigning existing C++ classes to new C structs; today's is to do with setting up new C++ classes from existing C structs. I think I'm done now!

Comment: @Walter You're right, it should be a size_t not an int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for this to work, the template class must derive from the type containing `n` and then you can access it as `T::n` where `T` is the template parameter.

(You can't access the inherited member using just `n` because that's not a *dependent name* and so the compiler will try to resolve it when the template itself is compiled, not later when it is instantiated, and no `n` exists within `MyArray` or at the global scope.  Using `T::n` causes it to be a dependent name -- depending on `T` -- and so resolution of the name is deferred until the template is instantiated.)

```
typedef struct {
    float *p;
    int n;
} float_array_C;

template <typename T>
class MyArray : public T
{
public:
    MyArray(int n_init) {
        T::n = n_init;
    }
};
```

Note that you will run into problems with code like this:

```
class Foo : public float_array_C, public MyArray<float_array_C> { /* ... */ };
```

In this case both `Foo` and `MyArray<float_array_C>` contain a *separate* instance of `float_array_C`.  You can use virtual inheritance for `float_array_C` if this is a problem:

```
template <typename T>
class MyArray : virtual public T { /* ... */ };

class Foo :
    virtual public float_array_C,
    public MyArray<float_array_C>
{ /* ... */ };
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach which only needs one template argument:

```
typedef struct {
    float *p;
    int n;
} float_array_C;

template<typename T> class MyArray : public T
{
public:
    MyArray(int n_init)
    {
        T::n = n_init;   
        contents.resize(T::n);
        T::p = contents.data();
    }       
private:
    std::vector<std::remove_pointer_t<decltype(T::p)>> contents;
};

typedef MyArray<float_array_C> floatArray;
```

Comment: I don't think this will compile. Did you try? You must at least `T::n=n_init`.

Comment: I can confirm that it compiles!

Comment: [g++ and clang both reject this code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d39ed1c3aa4b5d9b). `n` and `p` need to be dependent names, which means they must depend on `T`. **A compiler that accepts this code is a broken compiler.**

Comment: @cdhowie yes, I just tested it in ideone too. It compiles in VS2013 though.

Comment: @Axalo The Microsoft Visual C++ compiler is pretty much the canonical definition of "broken compiler."